# Beginner Python: Format Output

Tags: python, formatting, format

I was trying to finish an assignment until I reached this small issue.

My dilemma is: My output is printed correctly, but how do I get the key # and its respective output to be printed together neatly?

### Example:

- key 1: ABCDEB
- key 2: EFGFHI
- *etc*

### My Code:

```
def main():

    # hardcode
    phrase = raw_input ("Enter the phrase you would like to decode: ")

    # 1-26 alphabets (+3: A->D)
    # A starts at 65, and we want the ordinals to be from 0-25

    # everything must be in uppercase
    phrase = phrase.upper()

    # this makes up a list of the words in the phrase
    splitWords = phrase.split()

    output = ""


    for key in range(0,26):        

        # this function will split each word from the phrase
        for ch in splitWords:

            # split the words furthur into letters
            for x in ch:
                number = ((ord(x)-65) + key) % 26
                letter = (chr(number+65))

                # update accumulator variable
                output = output + letter

            # add a space after the word
            output = output + " "

    print "Key", key, ":", output

 main()
```

Comment: Well first off your indentation for the print statement is off. Unless that's from copying into SO. Secondly, you can do this: `print "Key " + key + ": " + output + "\n"`, notice the spaces and newline added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to reset `output` each loop, and `print` during each loop, so change:

```
output = ""
for key in range(0,26):        
    ## Other stuff
print "Key", key, ":", output
```

to:

```
for key in range(0,26):        
    output = ""
    ## Other stuff
    print "Key", key, ":", output
```

Old result:

```
Key 25 : MARK NBSL ... KYPI LZQJ
```

New result:

```
Key 0 : MARK 
Key 1 : NBSL 
   #etc
Key 24 : KYPI 
Key 25 : LZQJ
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in `print "Key", key, ":", output`, use `+` instead of `,` (so that you get proper string concatenation).

You want `key` and its corresponding `output` to print with every outer `for` loop iteration. I think I see why it's not happening at the moment. Hint: is your `print` statement actually falling under the outer loop right now?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [Input and Output section](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) of the users guide.  It goes through several methods of formatting strings.  Personally, I use the ["old"](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting) method still, but since you are learning I would suggest taking a look at the ["new"](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting) method.

If I wanted to output this prettily with the "old" method, I would do `print 'Key %3i: %r' % (key, output)`.  Here the `3i` indicates to give three spaces to an integer.